# Add hostnames with external vars_files

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I would like add my hostnames with external files.

I have used in my playbook master `vars_files` to add my hostnames, and it doesn't seem to be working.

I need to add the hostnames in external files from my ansible's project.
I cannot used hosts files and group, because I use [Ansible Tower (3.2.2)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/release-notes/relnotes.html#release-notes-for-3-2-x) and it have already his own inventory.

Please note I can't, for some reasons, add my `vars_files` in my Ansible's project.

I Have already tried to add the absolute path.
EDIT: Note the error message below is only via Ansible Tower execution.
With command line, it is working fine.

```
---

- hosts:  "{{ hostnames }}"

# include vars from file
  vars_files:
    # this line doesn't work
    - /project/ansible/home/ansible/ansible_scripts/vars/dev.yml
      # this line doesn't work
    # - /project/ansible/home/ansible/ansible_scripts/vars/dev.yml
      # this line doesn't work
    # - ../../../ansible/home/ansible/ansible_scripts/vars/dev.yml
    # this line works fine
    # - vars/dev.yml

# play roles
  roles: 
    - check_info_servers
```

The error is:

```
ERROR! vars file project/ansible/home/ansible/ansible_scripts/vars/dev.yml was not found on the Ansible Controller.
If you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option
```

Comment: 1) Are you using Ansible Tower or AWX? 2) Is it installed as Docker container on your server?

Comment: I'am using Ansible Tower

Comment: Not sure, but may be the error on absolute path is due to Tower virtualenv

Comment: May be you're rigth. i'am still noob with ansible Tower :(

Answer (score 0):

To **"add hostnames from external files"**  you might want use the [add_host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html#add-host-module) module.

For example:

```
> cat /scratch/dev.yml
my_hosts:
  - host1.example.com
  - host2.example.com
  - host3.example.com


> cat test.yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - /scratch/dev.yml
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_hosts }}"
    - debug: msg="{{ item }}"
      with_inventory_hostnames:
        - all


> ansible-playbook test.yaml | grep msg
    "msg": "host3.example.com"
    "msg": "host1.example.com"
    "msg": "host2.example.com"
```

Comment: Same issue with ansible Tower, but add_hosts module works fine with command line. Maybe it's not possible to add variables from external project via ansible Tower ...